# Magento 1 is not showing Dataflow Profile History

Tags: magento-1.9, dataflow, bug

This is Magento CE 1.9.3.2 installed from scratch, no themes, no extensions.

1. Go to Backend
2. From System -> Import/Export click on Dataflow Profiles
3. Click on profile with ID number 1 - Export All Products
4. Change the profile and Run it several times
5. Click on Profile History. You should see profile history. Click on [Search] button, nothing shows up. Select from Profile Action Run option do a Search, then Update option and do a Search. There are no rows showing up.

Checking Magento database, table [dataflow_profile_history] has information recorded. Column [action_code] has values like run and update.

Even the information is stored inside the database, Profile History in Dataflow Profiles is not showing information about Run, Create and Update of a profile. In my humble opinion this is a Magento bug. See the attachments.

Does anyone has a fix already for this issue?

[image: Backend Dataflow Profile]

[image: Dataflow Profile History Table]

Comment: first observation, user_id column is always 0. my admin user_id is 2. I changed the values from 0 to 2 and now all information appears in backend. there is no doubt this is a Magento issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the not correctly set `ùser_id`.

Fix ([LTS](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/428/commits/2eba98bad82aea00974a850ec2aba599d88485d2)):

> Mage_Dataflow_Model_Profile::_afterSave()

replace

```
$adminUserId = $this->getAdminUserId();
```

with

```
$adminUserId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
```

> Mage_Dataflow_Model_Profile::run()

replace

```
Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile_history')
    ->setProfileId($this->getId())
    ->setActionCode('run')
    ->save();
```

with

```
Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile_history')
    ->setProfileId($this->getId())
    ->setActionCode('run')
    ->setUserId(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId())
    ->save();
```

---

Source: http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2013/10/28/fixing-profile-history-magento-dataflow-profiles/

Comment: https://magento.com/tech-resources/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1675/